# How to accomplish the App Store Review Guideline related to Siri?

Tags: ios, app-store, siri

I've just read the `App Store Review Guidelines` and I got confused with this one:

> 2.27 If your app’s core functionality doesn’t work with the Siri remote it will be rejected. The app may, however, provide enhanced functionality in connection with a game controller or other peripheral

What should be done in the app to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably nothing - as long as you do not do some fishy things your app should work with the Siri remote without any problem.